# Query cache using infinispan

Tags: hibernate, jboss, infinispan

In my project I am using Jboss AS 7.1 server, hibernate 3.5 and java 1.7. For cache I am using infinispan 5.1.5 ("Brahma").By the following way I am configuring the cache in hibernate config xml.

`<prop key="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache">true</prop>
 <prop key="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache">true</prop>
<prop key="hibernate.transaction.manager_lookup_class">org.hibernate.transaction.JBossTransactionManagerLookup</prop>
<prop key="hibernate.cache.region.factory_class">org.hibernate.cache.infinispan.InfinispanRegionFactory</prop>
<prop key="hibernate.cache.infinispan.statistics">true</prop>
<prop key="hibernate.cache.infinispan.cfg">infinispan-config.xml</prop>`

and in my infinispan-config.xml

```
<default>
     <transaction
            transactionManagerLookupClass="org.infinispan.transaction.lookup.GenericTransactionManagerLookup"
            syncRollbackPhase="false"
            syncCommitPhase="false"
            cacheStopTimeout="30000"
            use1PcForAutoCommitTransactions="false"
            autoCommit="true"
            lockingMode="OPTIMISTIC"
            useSynchronization="false"
            transactionMode="TRANSACTIONAL"
     />
     <invocationBatching enabled="true" />
    <loaders passivation="true" shared="true" preload="true">
        <loader class="org.infinispan.loaders.file.FileCacheStore" fetchPersistentState="true"
            ignoreModifications="false" purgeOnStartup="false">
            <properties>
                <property name="location" value="/tmp/infinispan"/>
            </properties>
        </loader>
    </loaders> 
</default>
```

My questions:

1. How can I cache the queries which is used in the java class?
2. For hibernate hbm files the cache folder was created by infinispan, but cache file is not generated in the respective folder why?

Comment: can anyone help me in this issue please..?

Comment: Hello, unfortunately I'm not an expert in hibernate stuff. Apart of that I just noticed that you are configuring your FileCacheStore with passivation="true". And there is no <eviction> configured in your XML. In that case, eviction is disabled by default. What's important: config combination passivation enabled AND eviction disabled is invalid and Infinispan will log warnings. (Only a small insight when I can't help more now)

Comment: Thanks for your reply tsykora. Your suggestion is very useful for me because even I am also new to this platform..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That Infinispan configuration is all over the place and in no way follows the guidelines in the [default Infinispan configuration for Hibernate 2LC](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/blob/3.5/cache-infinispan/src/main/resources/org/hibernate/cache/infinispan/builder/infinispan-configs.xml). There's no need for passivation, it's just a cache! Hibernate itself is already your backend where data can be retrieved if not in the cache. No need for invocation catching and do not configure transactions at the Infinispan config level. Make sure transactions are configured correctly at the Hibernate level and those settings will be used in Infinispan.

Finally, I've created some demos for Hibernate 2LC with Infinispan [here](https://github.com/galderz/secondlc). Have a look at them where you'll see how you can do query caching :)

Comment: Hi Glader, first of all sorry for my late reply... and the demo helped me very much to understand the concept so thank you very much. But I am using select queries for my instance tables were I can't create any hibernate bean class(and hbm.xml files) for that.So while I am writing the select queries I am enabling the query cache by giving query.setCachable(true). But its not working.. is there any other way?...

Comment: @Ranjith keep in mind that the query cache is only useful when the *exact same* query is run multiple times without any database updates (and even then it may be of questionable use) http://tech.puredanger.com/2009/07/10/hibernate-query-cache/

Comment: @Ranjith, Shadow Creeper makes some very good points. Other than that I don't know. The demo contains a query specific example that works (https://github.com/galderz/secondlc/blob/master/src/test/java/secondlc/QueryWith2lcBenchmark.java), so I'd start with it, see if it works for you, then compare with yours and debug into the Hibernate code to see why query caching does not work. Remember to use stats to verify expectations.

Comment: Hi Glader, as you say, Shadow Creeper was right... now the cache is working fine... I used your code as my reference.... Thank you very much..:-)